# Call contract artifacts with same names from different path in hardhat

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to use a contract file with same name in 2 different folders:

```
src/
├── StfxVault.sol
├── gmx
│   ├── Reader.sol
│   ├── Stfx.sol
│   └── interfaces
│       └── IStfxGmx.sol
├── perp
│   ├── Reader.sol
│   ├── Stfx.sol
│   └── interfaces
│       └── IStfxPerp.sol
```

Here, I want to use `Reader` & `Stfx` from different directories in my Hardhat deploy script's `ethers.getContractFactory()` line.

In order to successfully deploy, right now I changed these for Gmx:

- `Reader` -> `GmxReader`
- `Stfx` -> `GmxStfx`

Is there any way to not change the name & still deploy successfully in case of hardhat?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by specifying the full path:

```js
const GmxReaderFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("src/gmx/Reader.sol:Reader");

const PerpReaderFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("src/perp/Reader.sol:Reader");
```